# Sum some elements in a list consisted of strings in C#

Tags: c#, linux, list, sum, cpu

I am trying to calculate the CPU usage per core from Linux with a C# code. When I execute `cat /proc/stat | grep cpu` my output looks exactly like the `cpu_usage` string. Then I am creating a list for each line and I want to calculate the CPU usage by `(1 - (cpu_usage_row_split[4] / sum(cpu_usage_row_split[1:]))) * 100` So in general I want to delete the fourth element in the list (idle CPU usage) to the sum of all the elements (user, nice, system, idle, iowait, irq, softirq) excluding the first one (the CPU number) in order to get the CPU usage of the separate CPU cores. I know I can simply convert the elements to integer and then sum each element, but I want to use something similar to Python's function `sum(lst[1:])`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string cpu_usage = @"cpu  16272 1158 46722 553911117 31493 0 158 0 0 0
    cpu0 2099 184 5874 34608555 408 0 56 0 0 0 
    cpu1 586 0 1544 34624437 314 0 12 0 0 0
    cpu2 1162 0 3184 34618796 1854 0 8 0 0 0
    cpu3 609 4 1594 34624014 411 0 3 0 0 0";

            string[] cpu_usage_arr = cpu_usage.Split('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < cpu_usage_arr.Length; i++)
            {
                string cpu_usage_row = cpu_usage_arr[i];
                string[] cpu_usage_row_split = cpu_usage_row.Split(' ');
                cpu_usage_row_split = cpu_usage_row_split.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you have to convert them to numbers if you want to sum them

Comment: but isn't it a shorter way to sum them without converting every single parameter `Int32.Parse(cpu_usage[1]) + Int32.Parse(cpu_usage[2]) +  ... + Int32.Parse(cpu_usage[7])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert strings to int:

```cs
var sum = cpu_usage_row_split.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Sum();
```

Comment: actually this will try to convert even the `cpu` into integer and the script will crash.

Comment: Then you can use int.TryParse()

Answer (score 1):

I would use `int.TryParse` to avoid getting a `System.FormatException` error when converting the strings to numbers.  The items that fail will add 0 to the SUM.  Wrapping `TryParse` in a static function I can use that function in `cpu_usage_row_split.Sum(x => AsInt(x))`

```
[TestMethod]
public void test_sum_string()
{
    string cpu_usage = @"cpu  16272 1158 46722 553911117 31493 0 158 0 0 0
    cpu0 2099 184 5874 34608555 408 0 56 0 0 0 
    cpu1 586 0 1544 34624437 314 0 12 0 0 0
    cpu2 1162 0 3184 34618796 1854 0 8 0 0 0
    cpu3 609 4 1594 34624014 411 0 3 0 0 0";

    string[] cpu_usage_arr = cpu_usage.Split('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < cpu_usage_arr.Length; i++)
    {
          string cpu_usage_row = cpu_usage_arr[i];
          string[] cpu_usage_row_split = cpu_usage_row.Split(' ');
          var totalUsage = cpu_usage_row_split.Sum(x => AsInt(x));
          Console.WriteLine(totalUsage);
    }
}

private static int AsInt(string value)
{
      int i = 0;
      bool b = int.TryParse(value, out i);
      return b ? i : 0;
}
```